# Sum a Specific Column When Multiple Records Exist

Tags: t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to sum a specific column to get a number total for each ID - but my result set is returning a result set that is a multiple of 6.

For example, the request_ID in my query has six docket_IDs associated with it and each docket_ID has six message_document_IDs associated.

Query:

```
SELECT r.id,
r.number_of_documents,
rc.docket_id,
rc.sequence_no,
rc.case_number_from_filer,
rd.number_of_pages,
rd.message_document_id,
r.received_date
FROM dbo.requests AS [r]
INNER JOIN dbo.request_court_documents_additonal_information AS [rc]
    ON r.id = rc.request_id
INNER JOIN dbo.request_document_additonal_information AS [rd]
    ON rd.request_id = r.id
WHERE CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) >= '10/1/2015'
  AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) <= '9/30/2016'
  AND rc.case_number_from_filer = 'NEW CASE'
  AND r.id = 32700637
ORDER BY r.id,
rc.docket_id,
rd.message_document_id;
```

The data set looks like:

```
id        docket_id  case_number  nbr_of_pgs  msg_doc_id  received_date
32700637  197085524  NEW CASE     18          DOC00001    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085524  NEW CASE     1           DOC00002    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085524  NEW CASE     4           DOC00003    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085524  NEW CASE     9           DOC00004    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085524  NEW CASE     9           DOC00005    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085524  NEW CASE     3           DOC00006    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085906  NEW CASE     18          DOC00001    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085906  NEW CASE     1           DOC00002    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085906  NEW CASE     4           DOC00003    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085906  NEW CASE     9           DOC00004    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085906  NEW CASE     9           DOC00005    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085906  NEW CASE     3           DOC00006    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085941  NEW CASE     18          DOC00001    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085941  NEW CASE     1           DOC00002    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085941  NEW CASE     4           DOC00003    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085941  NEW CASE     9           DOC00004    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085941  NEW CASE     9           DOC00005    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
32700637  197085941  NEW CASE     3           DOC00006    2015-10-01 00:01:32.590
```

This repeats itself three more times - so I return 36 rows worth of data and when I try to SUM (rd.number_of_pages) - my result is 6 times what I am expecting: 264 when it should be 44.

```
SELECT r.id,
SUM(rd.number_of_pages) AS [Pages]
FROM dbo.requests AS [r]
INNER JOIN dbo.request_court_documents_additonal_information AS [rc]
    ON r.id = rc.request_id
INNER JOIN dbo.request_document_additonal_information AS [rd]
    ON rd.request_id = r.id
WHERE CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) >= '10/1/2015'
  AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) <= '9/30/2016'
  AND rc.case_number_from_filer = 'NEW CASE'
  AND r.id = 32700637
GROUP BY r.id;
```

How can I eliminate the duplicate values from the docket_ids to return a true summation of the records?

Thanks,

Comment: try `sum(rd.number_of_pages) over (partition by id, docket_id order by received_date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way usint a correlated sub-query

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t

create table #t (id int, docket_id int, case_number varchar(64), nbr_of_pgs int, msg_doc_id varchar(64), received_date datetime)
insert into #t values
(32700637,197085524,'NEW CASE',18,'DOC00001','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085524,'NEW CASE',1,'DOC00002','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085524,'NEW CASE',4,'DOC00003','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085524,'NEW CASE',9,'DOC00004','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085524,'NEW CASE',9,'DOC00005','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085524,'NEW CASE',3,'DOC00006','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085906,'NEW CASE',18,'DOC00001','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085906,'NEW CASE',1,'DOC00002','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085906,'NEW CASE',4,'DOC00003','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085906,'NEW CASE',9,'DOC00004','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085906,'NEW CASE',9,'DOC00005','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085906,'NEW CASE',3,'DOC00006','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085941,'NEW CASE',18,'DOC00001','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085941,'NEW CASE',1,'DOC00002','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085941,'NEW CASE',4,'DOC00003','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085941,'NEW CASE',9,'DOC00004','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085941,'NEW CASE',9,'DOC00005','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590'),
(32700637,197085941,'NEW CASE',3,'DOC00006','2015-10-01 00:01:32.590')

select distinct id, ct as TotalNum 
from(
    select distinct
        id,
        docket_id,
        sum(nbr_of_pgs) as ct
    from 
        #t
    group by
        id, docket_id)x
```

**Your Query**

```
select distinct id, pages
from(
    SELECT 
        r.id,
        rc.docket_id,
        SUM(rd.number_of_pages) AS [Pages]
    FROM dbo.requests AS [r]
    INNER JOIN dbo.request_court_documents_additonal_information AS [rc]
        ON r.id = rc.request_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.request_document_additonal_information AS [rd]
        ON rd.request_id = r.id
    WHERE CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) >= '10/1/2015'
      AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) <= '9/30/2016'
      AND rc.case_number_from_filer = 'NEW CASE'
      AND r.id = 32700637
    GROUP BY r.id, rc.docket_id) x
```

Comment: Thanks scsimon - this is close. I'm getting a value of 35, which tells me it is most likely not summing one of the records with a value of 9 for the page count. Thought this might require the OVER / PARTITION BY but I wasn't sure how to write it.

Comment: @MISNole i used another way with test data for you. see the edit.

Comment: No worries, and Roll Tide :)